# Java - How to put thread on wait depending on a value in request?

Tags: java, database, multithreading

We have a REST Service which consumes JSON data. One of the tag is Analysis_Id.
Job of this service is to fetch data and throw it back. However, there is a quota restriction.
Request with specific value in Analysis_Id (lets say 1111) can submit requests only lets say 25 times. And this limit is configured in a table. When a request is made and REST service successfully throws back response, an insert is made in a transaction table. This table is checked whenever a new request is submitted to validate whether quota has already been exceeded or not.
Problem is that someone can submit multiple requests at the same time. To restrict that, we need to keep a request on hold if there is already a request being served with same Analysis_id.
What is the best approach to implement it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One add-on: While REST service is processing request with 1111 as Analysis_Id, it should keep any new request with same value on hold. However, if it receives another request with 2222 as Analysis_Id, it must go through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the same semantics of the `synchronized` keyword, but specific for one `Analysis_Id`, you can easily get it by manually maintaining locks:

```
//shared map
Map<String, Lock> locks = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(); //very important it's concurrent
...
//when a request arrives
locks.putIfAbsent(analysisId, new ReentrantLock()); //use computeIfAbsent if on Java 8
Lock lockForThisId = locks.get(analysisId);
lockForThisId.lock();
//do processing, update DB etc
lockForThisId.unlock();
```

But this only makes sense if the processing time is really short. In all other cases, you might want to introduce a queue of some kind. But that's a whole different game as it probably will involve asynchronous communication with the client.
You'd accept the request, enqueue it, and send a response immediately.
Then:

- the client could poll for status and get the result when done
- or you'd maintain a persistent connection (WebSockets come to mind)
  and send the result yourself when done
- or the client would have to provide a callback of some kind (a URL perhaps) that you'd invoke with the result when done.

You may also decide to only enqueue and process asynchronously when there's a request already in progress. Otherwise, you may process it directly and synchronously.

**EDIT:**
Answering your comments.

For the first question: why would you even do the locking in the first thread then? The thread that processes the request is the one that should lock/unlock, i.e. the new thread.

For the second, replace the simple `ConcurrentHashMap` with a proper cache and configure an expiry policy. In this case, there's no downside to removing a lock from the cache prematurely. It will get recreated when needed anyway. Just make absolutely sure the lock can not be removed if it's currently held by a thread.
You can try creating a cache by yourself using something like [this](http://chriswu.me/blog/a-lru-cache-in-10-lines-of-java/):

```
public class LRUCache<K, V> extends LinkedHashMap<K, V> {
  private int cacheSize;

  public LRUCache(int cacheSize) {
    super(16, 0.75, true);
    this.cacheSize = cacheSize;
  }

  protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry<K, V> eldest) {
    return size() >= cacheSize;
  }
}
```

And then wrap if it `Collections.synchronizedMap`, but a much better idea is to use a proper cache, like [Caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine) or [EHCache](http://www.ehcache.org/).

Comment: Thanks so much. Working as expected. However, there are two scenarios where I am stuck. I should have pointed out earlier.

Comment: One is that in some scenario, I need to create a new thread which will do the job. But the current thread cannot wait for this new thread to finish as the current thread needs to throw back some response. Hence responsibility for unlocking the lock would lie with this new thread. This is where it fails. As the new thread tries to unlock, it throws an exception IllegalMonitorStateException, probably because unlocking is taking place in a different scope. Any idea on workaround will be appreciated.

Comment: One more problem area is that the value of ID has some expiry date in the database. So after some time, may be after three months, no request would arrive with that value. But the map would still contain a Lock instance with that ID value as key. Over few months, map would have lots of keys which are not going to be used. Any idea how to tackle this.... Thanks in advance.